# Export musical note data to midi

Tags: c#, midi, notation

I've created some basic musical notation software in C#. I have a "Sound" class that contains useful properties (Note, NoteType (Semibreve, quaver, etc.). I currently have functions that can use instances of these "Sound" classes to create frequency and duration which are used to play the note.

Now, I would just like to export this information as a midi file, how can I do this?

Comment: Read the [Standard MIDI-File Format Spec.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/cmsip/readings/Standard-MIDI-file-format-updated.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need either a library to convert your list of notes to MIDI or create your own.
For the first option I didn't see any well documented library written in C#. However, you can check these two [C#-MIDI-Toolkit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6228/C-MIDI-Toolkit) and [midi.net](https://midinet.codeplex.com/)

For the second option, you first have to read [MIDI format specification](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html).Then you can encode your notes in terms of note on and note off events.

As an additional option, you may consider using other easy to use solutions written in [Python](https://mido.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Java](http://kevinboone.net/javamidi.html) at the list of notes to midi conversion stage